# Как получить файл формата .config модели нейронной сети Tensorflow?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, config

Необходимо получить файл конфигурации модели нейронной сети tensorflow. Знаю, что есть метод get_config, который, непосредственно показывает конфигурацию нейронной сети, но как ее сохранить в файл формата .config, так и не нашел конкретного ответа

Comment: А почему именно в `.config`? Я погуглил, там вроде обычно словарь получается, а словарь проще всего, например, в `json` сохранить.

Comment: Мне файл .config необходим для генерации файла с расширением .pbtxt из файла .pb. Пример: python tf_text_graph_faster_rcnn.py --input /path/to/model.pb --config /path/to/example.config --output /path/to/graph.pbtxt. В дальнейшем для использования в данной строке кода: cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow().